# Is the toString Method Unnecessary?

Tags: java, tostring

I was watching a tutorial on toStrings recently, since I still haven't used them much, and it occurred to me that there might be an easier way of accomplishing the same thing with less code. Surely enough, the code below produced the exact same result with less code.

If this is the case, then what is the point of a toString? Is there an advantage to using toStrings over the way I did it?

```
public class daughter{
    private static String name;
    private static int age;

    public daughter(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;

        System.out.println(name + ", " + age);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new daughter("Elizabeth", 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing `System.out.println()` of your `daughter` object in your `main` method.

Comment: I personally find toString() helpful in debugging. If I want to print the String representation of your object on demand, then I would do daughter.toString(). This is one of many helpful uses. Also, it is not really professional-like to automatically print something. You can't assume the user would want that printed anyways.

Comment: Item 10 : Always override tostring in Effective Java(Second Edition) by Joshua Bloch provided the best explanation.

Comment: Your code produces an exact different result! Your code prints stuff, when the constructor is called whether you want or not. If you want to print a `daughter` later, all you'll see is it's type and a hash of its memory location...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) `toString()`

> Returns a string representation of the object[...]

In fact, many native java methods and methods of libs
call this method to get a string representation.

For example [`Arrays.toString(Object[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) calls
toString for every object in the array a.
Or the [print](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29) methods of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) that takes
an object as argument calls it indirectly through
[`Strings.valueOf(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` method will help you in many cases

Following are at the top of my head

- If you want to just print object in pretty manner
- When you are debugging if you have `toString()` in expressive way then you won't have to expand the instance and see its field in debugger

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's because there's an internal toString (or equivalent that is to all practical purposes toString) called as part of the concatenation operator when you do that.

toString is still useful for greater control of the output formatting and such.  But if you don't need it, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your example works is actually due to `toString()`'s usefulness. You are concatenating a `String` object (`name`) and an `int` literal (`age`) with a `String` literal (`", "`) in your print statement. What this does is implicitly call `toString()` on everything being concatenated. A `String` object has a `toString()` method defined in it that returns the contents of the `String`'s internal `char` array for concatenation. The `int` simply uses its inherent value as a primitive (although there may be some [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) happening there to `Integer`, but that would just end up calling the `toString()` method defined in the `Integer` class anyway).

What you should really try is printing your actual `Daughter` object (I'm capitalizing `daughter` to `Daughter` since that's standard Java practice for class names):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Daughter d = new Daughter("Elizabeth", 7);
    System.out.println("Daughter: " + d);
}
```

You'll note that your output would look something like this:

> Daughter: Daughter@a62b39f

This is because you have no `toString()` method defined in your `Daughter` class, so it's using the return value of the [default `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) that is defined in the [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class (the "Mother of all Objects" as some people call it, since *all* objects in Java ultimately inherit from `java.lang.Object`). This default `toString()` method merely prints out the class name and the memory location at which that particular object resides (technically the object's hash code, but this is typically just the memory address, which is usually not that helpful anyway).

If you instead define a `toString()` method in your `Daughter` class like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.name + ", " + this.age;
}
```

then you should get output like this

> Daughter: Elizabeth, 7

when you call `System.out.println("Daughter: " + d);` in your `main` method (or anywhere else the `toString()` method is called, either explicitly or implicitly, on any `Daughter` object).

Answer (score 0):

Using `toString` method, you can print the info anywhere with a daughter object

Answer (score 0):

Simply Look at `Date` class it uses to `toString` to give the user the ability to see the current `Date&Time` in the Object :

```
System.out.println(new Date());
```

will print :
***Mon Aug 29 13:22:03 BST 2012***

besides it's ability to convert non String objects (-that can be converted to strings-)
to Strings
Ex:

```
Integer x=4;
System.out.println(x.toString)// prints: 4
```